# How can I create two different classes that have references to eachother within their code?

Tags: c++, class

How can I create two different classes that have references to eachother within their code in C++?

It would look something like this;

```
class A
{
    B b;
}
class B
{
    A a;
}
```

I get an error on the line of the

```
B b;
```

within class A stating;

error: 'B' was not declared in this scope

Rest easy in that I am not declaring a

```
B b = new B;
```

in A, nor am I declaring a

```
A a = new A;
```

in B, as I'm aware it would cause a StackOverflowException. I will use getters and setters to manipulate the data.

Comment: >StackOverflowException
Is this Java or C++?

Comment: To have "references to each other" requires... *references*. You don't have any.

Answer (score 1):

Use forward declarations, and make the members pointers.  It's easiest with two different headers, although it could be done in one:

```
// A.h
class B;

class A
{
    B* m_pB;
};
```

And:

```
// B.h
class A;

class B
{
    A* m_pA;
};
```

Then #include both headers in each .cpp file (A.cpp and B.cpp).

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you want:

```
class B;
class A
{
    B* b;
}
class B
{
    A* a;
}
```

Note that the class `B` is forward-declared as a class so that the compiler knows what it is when defining `A`. Also note that `A::b` is a *pointer* to `B` and `B::a` is a *pointer* to `A` (what you probably mean by "reference" if you come from a Java background). If `A::b` was declared to be of type `B` and `B::a` was declared to be of type `A` then each `A` object would literally contain an entire `B` object inside it and *vice versa*, which I'm guessing is not what you wanted (and is obviously impossible anyway).

Comment: What benefits would come from making the declarations of A and B within class B and A respectively pointers?

Comment: @user1973385 As opposed to what? Like I said, you can't have `A` inside `B` as well as *vice versa*. You could try C++ references (`A&`, `B&`) but that would be... tricky because how would you construct the first one?